# How to set background color inside another component? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

I wanto to make this:

[image]

as you can see, its a list of elements, each element will have its own background color, I want when I select one of them create above them a transparent background highlight? with this, I still can see the original background color of the note and this transparent highlight, I have this:

```
<View style = {{backgroundColor: "blue"}}> 
    <Text style = {{padding: 20, 
      flex: 1, backgroundColor: "red", opacity: 0.5, fontSize: 30, color: "black"}}>{item.title} 
    </Text>
</View>
```

as you can see, theres a view component with a background color of blue and a text component with the background color red and opacity 0.5, the problem is if I add opacity, they will combine creating the purple color, but if I dont, only will show the background color red

Comment: Does the answer help? -

Answer (score 0):

[Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@denistsoi/intrigued-kiwi)

You can use `TouchableWithoutFeedback` to handle onPress or if you don't care about the native transparent flash, you can use `TouchableOpacity`

Here I use useState to define which item in the list has been selected, and set the color to Red based on the styles.

```
import React, { useState } from "react"
import {
  View,
  FlatList,
  Text,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native"

const data = [{ title: "blach" }, { title: "lol" }]

export default function App() {
  const [selectedItem, toggleSelected] = useState(null)

  const renderItem = ({ item, index }) => {
    const toggleItem = (index) => {
      console.log(index)
      toggleSelected(index)
    }

    const isSelected = selectedItem === index
    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={(ev) => toggleItem(index)}>
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", marginBottom: 2 }}>
          <Text
            style={
              !isSelected
                ? styles.text
                : { ...styles.text, backgroundColor: "rgba(255,0,0,1)" }
            }
          >
            {item.title}
          </Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    )
  }

  return (
    <View style={{ paddingTop: 20 }}>
      <View style={{ padding: 10 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={renderItem}
          keyExtractor={(item, index) => `${item.title}_${index}`}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    padding: 20,
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#AB9F9F",
    fontSize: 30,
    color: "black",
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: "black",
  },
})
```